# Signature image using newlfm between closeline and sender name

Tags: graphics, newlfm, signatures

Is it possible to insert an image of my signature between the closing line and my name in a letter created with the class `newlfm`?

This is the code I have now:

```
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,orderfromtodate,sigleft,a4paper]{newlfm}
\usepackage{blindtext, xfrac}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@zfancyhead}{\fancy@reset}{\f@nch@reset}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyolh}{\f@nch@olh}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyolh}{\f@nch@olh}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyorh}{\f@nch@orh}{}{}
\makeatother

\newlfmP{dateskipbefore=50pt}
\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt}
\newlfmP{sigskipbefore=50pt}

\newlfmP{Headlinewd=0pt,Footlinewd=0pt}

\namefrom{John Smith}
\addrfrom{%
    221B Baker Street\\
    London, UK
}

\addrto{%
    Basil of Baker Street\\
    221$\sfrac{1}{2}$ Baker Street\\
    London, UK
}

\dateset{January 6, 1914}

\greetto{To Whom It May Concern,}

\closeline{Sincerely,}

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
    \blindtext
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried changing the closing part with:

```
\closeline{With best regards,\newline
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{signature.eps}}
```

This places the signature nicely just under "With best regards" but leaves too much spaces between the signature and "John Smith".

Comment: You can insert images using the `\includegraphics` command from the `graphicx` package

Comment: @siracusa I tried your suggestion and it works. I'm trying to remove the excessive space between the signature and the name under it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here has two parts:

1. Adding the signature as an image into the letter and
2. reducing the space between closing line and name.

**Solution point 1:** As already mentioned in the other answer you can use command `\signature` to place a photographed signatur into your letter after the closing line and before the printed (readable) name:

```
\signature{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}} % <============
```

Please see that I used an example image comming from package `mwe`, which must be installed but not called ...

**Solution point 2:** The distance between closing line and following image/name can be controlled for positive values (that means adding more space!) only with

```
\newlfmP{closeskipafter=0pt} % Skip after closeline before signature image <=================
```

There is a hard coded new line after the closing line you can only get rid off with patching command `\closeline` I did not investigate yet.

So the following mwe

```
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,orderfromtodate,sigleft,a4paper]{newlfm}

\usepackage{blindtext, xfrac}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@zfancyhead}{\fancy@reset}{\f@nch@reset}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyolh}{\f@nch@olh}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyolh}{\f@nch@olh}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyorh}{\f@nch@orh}{}{}
\makeatother

\newlfmP{dateskipbefore=50pt} % 
\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt}        % Size for written signature
\newlfmP{sigskipbefore=50pt}  % Skip between text and closeline 
\newlfmP{closeskipafter=50pt} % Skip after closeline before signature image <=================

\newlfmP{Headlinewd=0pt,Footlinewd=0pt}

\namefrom{John Smith}
\addrfrom{%
    221B Baker Street\\
    London, UK
}

\addrto{%
    Basil of Baker Street\\
    221$\sfrac{1}{2}$ Baker Street\\
    London, UK
}

\dateset{January 6, 1914}

\greetto{To Whom It May Concern,}

\closeline{Sincerely,}
\signature{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}} % <============

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
    \blindtext
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

you get the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

As you can see an example image simulation an hand written signature is added and there is an additional distance a defined with command `\newlfmP{closeskipafter=50pt}`.

Change the value in that command to `0pt` to get the minimal possible distance (please note: negative values doe not work!):

[image: resulting pdf with minimal space]

Comment: @down-voter: As usual here, explain your downvote!

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to put the signature image into the `\closeline` command. `newlfm` provides a special command `\signature` for this purpose that will also take care of properly adjusting the space around the signature image. So you can just use

```
\closeline{Sincerely,}
\signature{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{signature.eps}}
```

Using a thick rule instead of the signature image, the output looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer the OP's question, one way to remove the space between an image signature placed in the `\closeline` and the signature is to put the signature, too, in the `\closeline`. Like this

```
\closeline{
    Sincerely yours,\newline
    \includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=5cm]{example-image-a}\newline
    Mark Twain
}
\signame{}
```

The `\signame{}` serves to remove what would now be a double signature.
Although not elegant, this seems to be the only solution ATM to have no awkward space either above or below the signature image.